# LyX Empty Instant Preview Cache

Tags: lyx

I am using LyX's instant preview feather, and I've recently modified the script that called when compiling the instant preview, and it works as indented.

Problem is that when I open an existing document, all the math environments are already compiled in some sort of cache, and the script isn't called again.

Is there a way to empty this cache? I've tried to untick the "Convertor File Cache" option in the Convertros menu, and it hasn't helped.

Comment: Did the answer fix things for you or are you still seeing the problem after clearing the cache?

Answer (score 1):

1. Find your user directory by going to Help > About LyX. For me (on Linux) it is listed as `~/.lyx/`.
2. Open that directory in your file browser (in LyX 2.4 there will a button you can click on to do this so you don't have to copy/paste the path).
3. Exit LyX.
4. In the user directory, there should be a directory called "cache". Backup and then delete the files in that directory.
5. Open LyX again.